# Animate div with different width's and speed on click

Tags: jquery, canvas, jquery-animate

I've seen this website and a animate function that is so nice! But i'm not a jQuery pro and would love to understand how this registration-bg works that it animate's in that way.

http://www.thecapitol.pn/capitolconcerns -> click on the arrow in the middle

How is that possible that the div animates different width's with that different animation speed of each side? I've nothing found on the web that works this way.

**UPDATE**

```
$("#box1").click(function(e) {
    TweenMax.to(box, 0.5, {x: 500,y:0, rotation: 20});
    TweenMax.to(box, 0.5, {rotation: 10, delay: 0.3});
});

$("#box2").click(function(e) {
    TweenMax.to(box, 0.5, {x: 0,y:0, rotation: -5});
    TweenMax.to(box, 0.5, {rotation: 0, delay: 0.3});
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TRj2U/94/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it is achieved using `canvas`. The site source points to the [tweenmax](http://greensock.com/tweenmax). You can get more info at [Why GSAP](https://greensock.com/why-gsap/) page. You examine the source with a tool like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and take a closer look to the `abstractView` and `registration` js files..

Update:

1. GreenSock offers you this Cdn http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.13.2/TweenMax.min.js
2. Great source : [Tips for using the GreenSock Animation Platform](http://groupdocs.com/blog/tips-for-using-the-greensock-animation)
3. Try: `TweenMax.to($('#box'), 1, {x: -290,y:-300, rotation: 50, delay: 1.5});` after making your div 500px by 500px and margin:0

Comment: thanks for your fast response! http://jsfiddle.net/TRj2U/86/ i've created this fiddle but after a closer look at the js files this is what i've created. but I dont know how i can control each side of that drop down navigationbg.

Comment: You're welcome.. Please refer to my edit above.. Or take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/TRj2U/90/ you can easily play with it and find the result you want..

Comment: Hey Thank you so much! I've updated my fiddle with a working animation. But the animation lags ... how can i fix that? @wooer

Comment: It is a matter either of long reading to understand greensock gsap or of long trial and error to get the animation you think of which I cannot provide here except for showing you the way.. Bu you may check http://jsfiddle.net/TRj2U/97/ (where I have altered a bit the div leaving the scene.. watch it in fullscreen rather than in jsfiddle.. hope that it works fine for you) And thanks for such a nice question (+1) since you made me notice greensock gsap :)